# MySQL how do I omit a selection in my output?

Tags: mysql, phrase

I currently am stuck on this question:

*Display badge details for those employees who are not sales representatives. The format of the badge details is the first letter of the first name followed by a period, then the last name and then the title in upper case and enclosed in parentheses e.g. 
A. Fuller (VICE PRESIDENT, SALES)*

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, 

CONCAT(SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1, 1),

'.',

(LastName),

' ',

UPPER(title)

) as 'Badge Details'

 from Employees;
```

Everything is working fine for me so far, I am just having a bit of trouble with the part of 'Display badge details for those employees who are not sales representatives', how do I go about NOT displaying Sales Reps? I assume I build a 'WHERE' at the end of my stuff, I just can't figure out how to word it.

Sample Data of the Badge Details output:

```
N.Davolio SALES REPRESENTATIVE
A.Fuller VICE PRESIDENT, SALES
J.Leverling SALES REPRESENTATIVE
M.Peacock SALES REPRESENTATIVE
S.Buchanan SALES MANAGER
M.Suyama SALES REPRESENTATIVE
R.King SALES REPRESENTATIVE
L.Callahan INSIDE SALES COORDINATOR
A.Dodsworth SALES REPRESENTATIVE
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please show us your table structure (column names and types).

Comment: Hey mate, I'm still SUPER new to this, so please forgive my naivety here. How do I go about showing you that? Do you mean to show you where the data is coming from for Employees?

Comment: Show the columns of your table.  Also, you might want to show us some sample data.  Can an employee have more than one role?  For example, if an employee were a sales rep _and_ another role, should he be excluded or included?

Comment: The columns I am using is First Name, Last Name and then Badge Details. This is a list of the results so far, without excluding sales rep. 
N.Davolio SALES REPRESENTATIVE
A.Fuller VICE PRESIDENT, SALES
J.Leverling SALES REPRESENTATIVE
M.Peacock SALES REPRESENTATIVE
S.Buchanan SALES MANAGER
M.Suyama SALES REPRESENTATIVE
R.King SALES REPRESENTATIVE
L.Callahan INSIDE SALES COORDINATOR
A.Dodsworth SALES REPRESENTATIVE

Comment: Sorry that came out a bit messy in the format. But no, no one has more than one role. It's either Sales Representative, or a different title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can identify sales reps as having the title `SALES REPRESENTATIVE`, and also assuming that each employee can have only one role, then you should be able to just add a `WHERE` clause which removes the sales reps:

```
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       CONCAT(SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1, 1),
              '.',
              LastName,
              ' ',
              '(', UPPER(title), ')'

             ) AS `Badge Details`
FROM Employees
WHERE UPPER(title) <> 'SALES REPRESENTATIVE'
```

Comment: Hmmm, I just tried this but it still gives me all of the Sales Representatives.

Comment: This is why I asked to see some sample data.  You still have not showed any.

Comment: Was that not what I wrote in the comment up a bit? I'll put it in to my original post so it's formatted as a bit of a better list.

Comment: Have a look now mate, I've added it as a list in my OP.

Comment: Try the query again, I had a capitalization problem.  I really wanted to see your _original_ data, not output from an incorrect query.

Comment: Thanks so much Tim, that is perfect :)